# Number of heads when flipping three coins

Tags: probability

> Three coins are flipped, each independent of each other. What is the probability that the number of heads will be greater than 0, 1, and 2?

The answers as given by my answer sheet are $\frac78$, $\frac12$ and $\frac18$. What is actually going on? Binomial theorem, Independence, what am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

You are asking three specific questions, I will answer one general question:

> What is the probability of $X>n$?

---

Split it into **disjoint** events, and then add up their probabilities:

$$P(X>n)=\sum\limits_{k=n+1}^{3}\binom3k\cdot\left(\frac12\right)^{k}\cdot\left(1-\frac12\right)^{3-k}$$

Answer (score 1):

$$P(\text{exactly $n$ heads})=\frac{\text{# of ways to choose $n$ out of $3$ coins to have heads}}{\text{# of possible outcomes}}=\frac{\large\binom{3}{n}}{2^3}$$

Thus, for example,
$$\begin{align*}
P(\text{more than 1 head})&=P(\text{exactly 2 heads})+P(\text{exactly 3 heads})\\\\
&=\frac{\large\binom{3}{2}}{2^3}+\frac{\large\binom{3}{3}}{2^3}\\\\
&=\frac{3}{8}+\frac{1}{8}\\\\
&=\frac{1}{2}
\end{align*}$$

Answer (score 1):

The count of successes among $n$ Bernoulli events of success rate $p$ has a Binomial Distribution.  $$X\sim \mathcal {Bin}(n, p) \iff \mathsf P(X=k) = \binom n k p^k(1-p)^{n-k} \quad\Big[k\in \Bbb Z{\cap}[0;n]\Big]$$

Which is indeed derived from the Binomial Theorem, as $\mathsf P(X=k)$ corresponds to the $\underline\;\,p^k$ term of the expansion for $(p+q)^n$ where $q=1-p$ .

When $n=3, p=1/2$, then $\mathsf P(X=k) = \dbinom 3 k 2^{-3}\quad\Big[k\in \{0,1,2,3\}\Big]$

Hence $\mathsf P(X>3) = 0 \\ \mathsf P(X>2) = 0 + \tfrac 18\binom 3 3 = \tfrac 18\\ \mathsf P(X>1) = \tfrac 1 8+\tfrac 18\binom 3 2 = \tfrac 4 8 \\ \mathsf P(X>0) = \tfrac 4 8 + \tfrac 1 8\binom 3 1 = \tfrac 7 8 \\ \mathsf P(X> {-}1) = \tfrac 78 + \tfrac 1 8\binom 3 0 = 1$

Answer (score 0):

Although this type of question usually requires calculations based on the binomial distribution, as set out in other answers, it's worth noting that the specific question asking for the probability of the number of heads being greater than $1$ can be answered by appeal to symmetry.  Assuming the coins are fair, by symmetry we have:

$$P(\text{more than one head}) = P(\text{more than one tail})$$

Also, if 3 coins are tossed, the outcome must include more than one head, or more than one tail, but not both, so we have:

$$P(\text{more than one head}) + P(\text{more than one tail}) = 1$$

Hence:

$$P(\text{more than one head}) = P(\text{more than one tail}) = \frac{1}{2}$$